# How to use Foreach with PhpQuery?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, phpquery

I'm trying to parse some html with PhpQuery, but it is not easy for me...

I need to extract only the URL(href tag) to an array but it is not working.

Please see this code for example purposes only:

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML('<div align = "left" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #C3D9FF"> </p>

        <table cellPadding="2" cellSpacing="0" width="100%" height="60" style="border-collapse: collapse; ">

          <tr>
            <td align="left" width="531" height="20"><small>
            <strong>

            <a href="/1153414/">

            <font style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Industrial</font><a/> </a></small></strong>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="100%" height="1">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="736">
              <tr>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="67">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">
                Data:</font></strong></td>

                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="150">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;4-1-2011 </font></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="59">
                <font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Zona:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="473">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp; Castelo Branco</font></td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="67">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Categoria:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="150">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;Indústria / Produção </font></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="59">

                <font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Empresa:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="473">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;Isotransfo, Unipessoal LDA</font></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
            </td>

          </tr>
        </table>

 </p>

        <table cellPadding="2" cellSpacing="0" width="100%" height="60" style="border-collapse: collapse; ">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" width="531" height="20"><small>
            <strong>

            <a href="/1153399/">

            <font style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Admite-se<a/> </a> </font></small></strong>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="100%" height="1">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="736">

              <tr>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="67">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">
                Data:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="150">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;4-1-2011 </font></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="59">

                <font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Zona:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="473">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp; Castelo Branco</font></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>

                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="67">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Categoria:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="150">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;Indústria / Produção </font></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="59">
                <font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">

                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Empresa:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="473">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;Isotransfo, Unipessoal LDA</font></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

 </p>

        <table cellPadding="2" cellSpacing="0" width="100%" height="60" style="border-collapse: collapse; ">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" width="531" height="20"><small><font face="Arial">
            <strong>

            <a href="/1153280/">

            <font style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Precisa-se</font><a/> </a> </font></small></strong>

            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="100%" height="1">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="736">
              <tr>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="67">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">

                Data:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="150">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;4-1-2011 </font></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="59">
                <font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Zona:</font></strong></td>

                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="473">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp; ( Todas as Zonas )</font></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="67">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Categoria:</font></strong></td>

                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="150">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;Saúde / Medicina / Enfermagem </font></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="59">
                <font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Empresa:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="473">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;Emprego Radiologia</font></td>

              </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

 </p>

        <table cellPadding="2" cellSpacing="0" width="100%" height="60" style="border-collapse: collapse; ">
          <tr>

            <td align="left" width="531" height="20"><small><font face="Arial">
            <strong>

            <a href="/1152665/">

            <font style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Operadores</font><a/> </a> </font></small></strong>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="100%" height="1">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="736">
              <tr>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="67">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">
                Data:</font></strong></td>

                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="150">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;4-1-2011 </font></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="59">
                <font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Zona:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="473">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp; Viseu</font></td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="67">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Categoria:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="150">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;Lojas / Comércio / Balcão </font></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="59">

                <font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Empresa:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="473">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;Dia Portugal Supermercados - Soc. Unip., Lda.</font></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
            </td>

          </tr>
        </table>

 </p>

        <table cellPadding="2" cellSpacing="0" width="100%" height="60" style="border-collapse: collapse; ">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" width="531" height="20"><small><font face="Arial">
            <strong>

            <a href="/1153524/">

            <font style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Responsável</font><a/> </a> </font></small></strong>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="100%" height="1">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="736">

              <tr>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="67">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">
                Data:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="150">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;4-1-2011 </font></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="59">

                <font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Zona:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="473">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp; Santarem</font></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>

                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="67">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">
                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Categoria:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="150">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;Comercial / Vendas </font></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="59">
                <font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">
                <strong style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px; font-weight:400">

                <font face="Arial" color="#333333" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">Empresa:</font></strong></td>
                <td align="left" vAlign="top" width="473">
                <font face="Arial" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; LINE-HEIGHT: 14px">&nbsp;ALDI Supermercados Lda.</font></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</div>');
//echo $doc['div table a']->attr('href');
foreach ($doc['div table a'] as $a) {
    $hrefs[] .= pq($a)->attr('href');
}
print_r ($hrefs);
```

If I echo out the code bellow it get's me only the href url, and it is ok:

```
echo $doc['div table a']->attr('href');
```

If I run the foreach statement I got an array with some null values:

```
foreach ($doc['div table a'] as $a) {
    $hrefs[] .= pq($a)->attr('href');
}
print_r ($hrefs);
```

The array I got is:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => /1153414/ 
    [1] => 
    [2] => /1153399/ 
    [3] => 
    [4] => /1153280/ 
    [5] => 
    [6] => /1152665/ 
    [7] => 
    [8] => /1153524/ 
    [9] => 
    )
```

How can I generate an array like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => /1153414/ 
    [1] => /1153399/ 
    [2] => /1153280/ 
    [3] => /1152665/ 
    [4] => /1153524/ 
    )
```

If you can give me some clues, I would be appreciated.

Sorry my bad english

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have five instances of `<a/>` in your code.  This creates an empty `a` element, rather than closing an existing one. Remove them and your code should work fine.

---

**Edit** A very simple way of removing empty values from an array is running [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with no second argument:

```
$hrefs = array_filter($hrefs);
```

Comment: How! I see. The HTML is not mine, is from a website I need to scrap. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (pq($a)->attr('href') != '') {
   $hrefs[] .= pq($a)->attr('href');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works! Do you understand why when I specify the "attr('href')" on the foreach I got the ''?

Comment: @What is the Question, your solution resolves the problem "array_filter($hrefs)" does the job in a silent way.

Comment: @Andre, lonesomeday was quicker at explaining :)